# How to make bootstrap loader lay on div?

Tags: css

im so clueless in css,I have a loader,when i click the function it just starts below the image ina div which is so ugly,i want it to come over, it any idea?

```
     <div class="card" (click)="SendToBank($event)">

          <div class="k-block" *ngIf="loadingSpinner">
              <div class="spinner-border text-info" role="status" > 
              <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            
              <img class="bank-logo" src="../assets/Img/2.png" id="seb">
            
            <span> SEB</span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

any idea how i can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Well you just need to position it fixed and style it a little bit.

Read more here [css position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

I left out the Angular related code.

```css
.k-block {
    position:fixed;
    display:flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}
```

```html
 <div class="card">

   <div class="k-block">
     <div class="spinner-border text-info" role="status">
       <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card-body">

     <img class="bank-logo" src="../assets/Img/2.png" id="seb">

     <span> SEB</span>
   </div>
 </div>
```